# How to determine whether “and” connects words or parts of sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, conjunctions

The sight of the little Breton peasant who did her humble housework aroused in her despairing regrets and ________ dreams.(distract)

Distracted or Distracting? Which one should I choose?

I think the problem is I don’t know whether the “and” connects (a) verb + verb or (b) noun + noun.

Answer (score 2):

The word "and" connects the "regrets" and "dreams." Whether or not one uses "distracted" or "distracting" depends on which best describes the dreams. Unlike many words with these suffixes, the two words do not mean the same kind of dreams.

***Distracted dreams*** are those weird kind of night-time dreams that are torn by anxiety and leave one feeling as though suspended in space.

***Distracting dreams*** take away one's concentration from other life responsibilities. These can be hopes and dreams for the future, such as getting married or getting one's dream job. These dreams can preoccupy one's mind during the daytime to the extent that one can hardly concentrate on everyday life and duties.

That is how the words are generally used in the literature I have seen with reference to dreams. I don't find the dictionary definitions very useful. All the same, here are Google's definitions for what they're worth:

[Distracted Definition](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02D3SZNGRTbsWNDgtp7ePaDt2f8hQ%3A1586732494694&ei=zp2TXtf6KeSc_QbSmZH4Dw&q=distracted%20definition&oq=distracted%20definition&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgIIADIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB46BAgAEEdKCQgXEgUxMi0zNkoICBgSBDEyLTNQ1NYBWNTWAWDj4wFoAHACeACAAVOIAVOSAQExmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjXmcyV_-PoAhVkTt8KHdJMBP8Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)

> *adjective*
>
> unable to concentrate because one's mind is preoccupied.
>
> "Charlotte seemed too distracted to give him much attention"

[Distracting Definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=distracting%20definition&oq=distracting%20d&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.6709j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> *adjective*
>
> preventing concentration or diverting attention; disturbing.
>
> "she found his nearness distracting"

Since no context is provided for the above quote, I cannot advise which adjective should be used, i.e. whether the dreams were distracted or distracting. I will let you decide, based on the definitions I provided. From here on, in this answer I will speak about "despairing regrets and [distracted/distracting] dreams" to indicate that the choice has been left open.

**How to determine whether “and” connects words or parts of sentences?**

To determine how we know what is being connected by the word "and," let's parse the sentence:

> The sight of the little Breton peasant who did her humble housework
>   aroused in her despairing regrets and [distracted/distracting] dreams.

**Subject**: sight

**Object of subject "sight"**: little Breton peasant [who did her humble housework]

**Predicate**: aroused

**Object of predicate "aroused"**: regrets, dreams

**Modifiers of objects "regrets" and "dreams"**: despairing, distracted/distracting

Parsed this way, there is only one predicate. The only two equal words that can be connected are the two nouns: regrets, dreams.

**Two Verbs**

You ask whether "and" could join two verbs. The other verb in that sentence is "did." It appears in this sentence fragment:

> the little Breton peasant who did her humble housework

This is not a grammatically correct sentence; the word "who" makes it subordinate, i.e. the object of "sight," as described above.

Because this part is subordinate, it is not at all equal to the predicate "aroused." Thus, "did" cannot be connected with "aroused."

**Testing the Connection**

Look at it another way: It makes no sense to say "did aroused." That is not grammatically correct because "did" is past tense and "aroused" is past tense. One can say "did arouse," because "did" puts "arouse" in the past tense, but not "did aroused." Nor does it make sense to say "did and aroused." Those two words are not equal in this quote.

However, one can say "regrets and dreams." Both these nouns are objects that were aroused by the sight. Because both nouns are objects of the same verb, they are equal status and can be connected. It also sounds right to join them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Perhaps it was my expression that confused you. When I say verb +verb, I mean could it be possible that “and” connects “aroused” and “distracted” , which means “distracted” here is a verb. So here is two possibilities:(a) aroused in regrets and distracted dreams (b)aroused in despairing regrets and distracting dreams. I don’t know how to choose.

Comment: "Distracted" is not a verb in this sentence because it is used to modify or describe the word "dreams." I think I demonstrated how that works when I parsed the sentence.

Comment: @user112563, it is incorrect to say "aroused in regrets." See how I parsed that sentence. I think you misunderstand my answer. Feel free to tell me what part is unclear.